# SQL return a Syntax error or access violation: 1064 during migration with symfony

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony

I want to add a trigger that insert the new state of my ride entity into the ride_history entity:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER after_updating_changes
AFTER UPDATE ON ride 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF OLD.status_id <> NEW.status_id THEN 
        INSERT INTO ride_history(`ride_id`, `status`, `created`) 
        VALUES(NEW.id, NEW.status_id, NOW());
    END IF;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

I already tested it on phpmyadmin and there was no error during execution, but when I put it into my migration file and try to migrate the database, symfony returns this error:

```
An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL synt
  ax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER // CREATE TRIGGER after_
  updating_changes AFTER UPDATE ON ride FOR E...' at line 1
```

So i'm a bit lost into all this, please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DELIMITER is client command, not SQL statement. So it causes an error while using as SQL statement.

Convert your trigger text to single-statement form making `DELIMITER` command unneeded:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER after_updating_changes
AFTER UPDATE ON ride 
FOR EACH ROW
    INSERT INTO ride_history(`ride_id`, `status`, `created`) 
    SELECT NEW.id, NEW.status_id, NOW()
    WHERE OLD.status_id <> NEW.status_id;
```

PS. Take into account that if any `status_id` value is NULL then none will be saved into the history table. So you must adjust WHERE condition accordingly if this column is nullable.

Comment: It resolved it! Thank you